# Cannot select text on my page

Tags: html, css, text, positioning

Thanks for reading and any help will be gladly appreciated.

My problem is that I cannot select text on a webpage that I built. I'm new to programming, and still do not understand the ins and outs of everything. But I'm trying hard to learn.
The entire page is positioned relative, and I have done research and read other posts about the relative positioning being an issue when selecting text. I know I can get around this issue, because the page I modeled mine after is positioned relative, and you can select text just fine on this page.

This is my page: www.the-daily-prophet.com

I'm sure this might be an easy fix, but I cannot figure it out.
Thanks for any help, and I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: It looks like your page is made up of images, which is why you can't select the text

Comment: @Rich - Nope... but one of the DIVs are layed over the rest of the content.. don't know which yet

Answer (score 3):

Your footer is ending up above your main text columns. Removing `position: relative; margin-left: 562px;` from the footer resolves that problem for me in Chrome, although it may have unintended consequences.

Comment: James, thanks so much for your help! That took care of the problem and the page looks just fine. Thanks again for helping out a newbie.